# How to GET RID of the iFRAME on Azure that wraps my website I uploaded via FTP

Tags: iframe, azure-web-app-service

this is driving me NUTS!

I have a website I built that's on AZURE.

I built it in NETBEANS 8.2 like I do with EVERY SITE since 2011.

I uploaded to AZURE via FILEZILLA with no issue. When I got to login, BOOM! I get this error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

It's because of AZURE WRAPPING MY SITE with TWO IFRAMES!!! Whiskey Tango Foxtrot???

When I'm on my 1and1 DEDICATED SERVER and NOT a VIRTUALIZED AZURE SERVER, I have ZERO PROBLEMS and no IFRAMES!

PLEASE SOMEONE TELL ME HOW TO GET RID OF THIS ANNOYANCE???

UPDATE: BRANDO, here's the config on Azure for Virtual Directories. It's pretty straight forward and I get an iFRAME!!! Azure "IS" doing this!![image: ![Azure APP CONFIG SETTINGS for Virtual DIrectories]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW6Ha.png)

[image: INSPECTOR CONSOLE SHOWING DUAL IFRAMES on AZURE]

Comment: As far as I know, azure will not change your code after you uploaded the website. I guess  this may be a Implanted ads. Because, the thingbluapp is also use the azure website, so you may consider azure add codes to your website. I suggest you could post your website link and we could see the source code in our side to check if it is a Implanted ads.

Comment: The link is here: www.thingblu.com.  the structure is like so:  /site/wwwroot/tbsite. Heck if I know where the iFrame is coming from?  This doesn't happen with my dedicated server on 1and1.com which is a windows 2012 REAL SERVER and not VIRTUALIZED GARBAGE like Azure. It's not USER friendly, intuitive or TIME Saving and when I can knock out and upload a site quickly, this has been not only racking my brain but that of my offshore colleagues that are PowerBI and asp.net guys. Problem is, I've been uploading and developing sites for nearly 30 years and I've been using Azure for 3 mos and well...

Comment: This site is a simple BOOTSTRAP HTML5/CSS3 site and is NOT rocket science.

Comment: According to your description, I found your azure web site is http://thingbluapp.azurewebsites.net/tbsite/. In this website, azure doesn't add anything. But in the www.thingblu.com url add the frameset. Could you please tell us how you bind the custom url to azure web app? Does this two url redirect two different azure server?

Comment: Brando, thank you for responding. How I bind the app is this way: Virtual applications and directories
/ <-- THIS IS SET HERE with a SLASH
site\wwwroot\thingblugrow <-- THIS IS SET LIKE THIS
Application <-- THE APPLICATION LINK IS CHECKED!  I can snap a pic if you'd like.

Comment: I know you have set virtual applications and directories in application settings, but it will not add the frame set to your web site. What I mean is I guess the custom url hosting company add the frame set not the azure. So I suggest you post the information about how you bind the www.thingblu.com custom url with the thingbluapp.azurewebsites.net/tbsite.

Comment: Brando, it's bound in Azure under... SEE UPDATE ABOVE. I'm telling you, I BUILT the site and simply UPLOADED to a sub directory under wwwroot on azure. NO IFRAMES AT ALL WHATSOEVER. I built it in angular / bootstrap / HTML5 / CSS3. Pretty much that's it. ALL OPEN SOURCE TECH.  When I access the page, I get an iframe as indicated in the first graphic.  THIS MAKES NO SENSE to me!

Comment: I have create a angular-2 project and use ftp upload to the azure as you says. It doesn't add the frameset, you could access this url:http://brandotestforvisualpath.azurewebsites.net/. This is virtual directories setting image:http://imgur.com/jtgIo59. I couldn't repro your issue. I suggest you could create a new angular project and publish to azure again to test it. Azure will not add the code.If the azure add the frame set, I suggest you could post your test demo code to me to repro your issue.

Comment: Brando, let me do that. I have to take my grandson to a doc appt, so it will be later this afternoon. I think I've reached the point where I need to blow it out and start the app over again, as you have stated.  Thank you and I'll get you the results shortly.  Be patient.

Comment: Brando, NO JOY, sir. Here's where I'm at.  The site: www.thingblu.com is also, now screwed up.  If you go there, you'll see www.thingblu.com, and go to ELEMENTS, expand all and you'll see, FRAMESET ROWS, the FRAMESET THEN #document.  If you go to www.thingblugrow.com, you'll see the same EXACT thing.  The error is NOT on the domains but on the FRAMESETS... WHY ARE THESE FRAMESETS HAPPENING?  Now a colleague tried your solution and set up a BOOTSTRAP site, through FileZilla. Here's the link: http://testappinnovyt.azurewebsites.net/  but he's on his OWN server, NOT thingbluapp.azurewebsites.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure web app will not add any codes to your html page.It is just a host platform.

www.thingblugrow.com/www.thingblu.com <--- custom domain, add the frameset

testappinnovyt.azurewebsites.net/thingbluapp.azurewebsites.net <--- azure web site doesn't add the frameset

[image]

So this issue is not related with azure web app.

So I guess the frame set is added by your custom domain company server or you set the frame by code at some other place(by js) not the azure.

I suggest you could try to connect with your custom domain support and could  follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) to bind the custom domain with your azure web app.

Comment: Brando, thank you and guess what, the IFRAMES are gone now. MSFT has opened a case BECAUSE OF YOUR comments, man!!!  I was on the line with Roger Juan in China until 3 AM and he's studied your comments and pointed me to the on-premise migration tool. VERY COOL... Here's the link:   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-migration-from-iis-server  Also, this is what I'm getting now, sir. The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  This is BETTER!!!  Brando, the CASE number is: SR number 117061415890761.

Comment: Also, this is what MSFT told me to do:What I need to do now is to scale your web app to large web app for 1 hour the scale down again.
can you please turn on diagnostics logs on your web app file system:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

If you have any questions or concerns, please let me know.

Comment: I'm getting 503 SERVER IS UNAVAILABLE now... here's a SO solution I'm going to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790684/why-does-azure-give-me-an-intermittent-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable

Comment: Brando, so the diagnostics are still running but the iFRAMES are back. I respectfully disagree with you your assessment. Innovyt made there site via Visual Studio and I simply uploaded like I've always done with FILEZILLA as FTP which WE can do. So, no, FileZilla does not create iFrames and neither does NetBeans as it's what I've used for years onsite at various jobs and at home for private clients.  I'm confused and so is Roger Juan at MSFT in CHINA regarding this issue.  Try www.thingblu.com or thingbluapp.azurewebsites.net/tbsite and you'll see and iFrame in one and none in the other

Comment: Hi peter, could you please tell me how you bind your custom domain:www.thingblu.com with the azure web app:thingbluapp.azurewebsites.net? Do you use the azure web app's custom domain feature?Or bind the website by anther way?

Comment: GOT IT! You won't believe it... and you can shoot me... Getting rid of the Web.Config file solved the issue... I feel SO STUPID!  I'm Upvoting and SELECTING your answer, Brando... THANK YOU!  Try it: www.thingblu.com with ZERO iFRAMES!  Who'd ah thunk it!